# Stop tabs to move to original on refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using CSS tabs on which I am putting different data to view. But whenever I refresh the page the tabs automatically moves to first tab.

Is there any way to stop the tabs moving automatically to the first one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vtab.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.opacityrollover.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
            <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0"  alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html5.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <![endif]-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">


</head>
<body id="page1">
    <!--==============================header=================================-->
    <header>

    <div class="row-2">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="container_12">
                    <div class="grid_9">
                    <div id="logom">
                    <img src="images/logo-iie.png" width="43" height="54" alt="IIE LOGO" />
                    </div>
                        <h1>
                            <a class="logo" href="index.html">Indian Institute of Entrepreneurship</a>
                            <span>Clusters in North East Region</span>
                        </h1>
                        An Organisation of the Ministry Of Micro, Small and Medium Enterprises(MSME),<br>
                      Govt.of India
An ISO 9001:2008 Certified Organisation 
                    </div>
<div id="logor"><img src="images/logo-rrc.png" width="51" height="54" alt="IIE LOGO" /></div> 
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-1">
            <div class="main">
                <div class="container_12">
                    <div class="grid_12">
                        <!-- Main navigation -->
    <nav class="main-navigation clearfix span12" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.html">RRC Team</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="clusters.html">Clusters</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Assam</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Sipajhar Handloom Cluster</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dhamdhama Handloom Cluster</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pyranga Eri Cluster</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Rontholi Jewellery Cluster</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bogulamari Jute Cluster</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Asharikandi Terracotta Cluster</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#">Japi Cluster</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Incense Sticks cluster</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manipur</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Kouna Grass Cluster</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Imphal Handloom Cluster</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Greater Imphal Jewellery Cluster</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mizoram</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Baktwang Wood Carpentry Cluster</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Bairabi Bamboo cluster</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sikkim</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Okhrey Carpet Making Cluster</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Tripura</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Hapania Jute Cluster</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li> 
                    <li><a href="#">Meghalaya</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Strawberry Cluster, Ri-Bhoi</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Umden Eri Cluster</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cashew Nut Cluster, Selsela</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Arunachal Pradesh</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Tawang Carpet Making Cluster</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dirang Food Processing Cluster</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="current"><a href="gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> <!-- #main-navigation -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

    </header>

<!-- content -->
    <section id="content">
        <div class="bg-top">
            <div class="bg-top-2">
                <div class="bg">
                    <div class="bg-top-shadow">
                        <div class="main">
                            <div class="gallery p3">
                                <div class="wrapper indent-bot">
                                   <span class="title img-indent3">Gallery</span><img src="images/gall-top.jpg" width="800" height="82">                                  <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
                                     <!--------------------------------------->

 <div id="w" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="sidemenu">

      <li>
        <a href="#assam-content" class="open"><i class="icon-info-sign icon-large"></i><strong>Assam</strong></a>
      </li>      
      <li>
        <a href="#manipur-content"><i class="icon-lightbulb icon-large"></i><strong>Manipur</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#mizoram-content"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i><strong>Mizoram</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#sikkim-content"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i><strong>Sikkim</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tripura-content"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i><strong>Tripura</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#meghalaya-content"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i><strong>Meghalaya</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#arunachal-content"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i><strong>Arunachal</strong></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="contab">   

        <div id="assam-content" class="contabblock">
          <span class="cluster">Photographs of Assam</span>

          <!-- Asharikandi Cluster -->
          <span class="cluster-name">Asharikandi Cluster</span>
          <div class="image-row">
                    <div class="image-set">
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Asharikandi Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Asharikandi Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Asharikandi Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Asharikandi Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Asharikandi Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Asharikandi Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/demopage/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Asharikandi Cluster -->
            <!-- Pyranga Cluster -->
            <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
            <span class="cluster-name">Pyranga Eri Cluster</span>
            <div class="image-row">
                    <div class="image-set">
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/pyranga-eri/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Pyranga Eri Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/pyranga-eri/thumb-1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/pyranga-eri/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Pyranga Eri Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/pyranga-eri/thumb-2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/pyranga-eri/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Pyranga Eri Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/pyranga-eri/thumb-3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/pyranga-eri/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Pyranga Eri Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/pyranga-eri/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/pyranga-eri/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Pyranga Eri Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/pyranga-eri/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/pyranga-eri/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Pyranga Eri Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/pyranga-eri/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Pyranga Cluster  -->
            <!-- Rontholi Jewellery Cluster -->
            <div class="cleaner_h10"></div>
            <span class="cluster-name">Rontholi Jewellery Cluster</span>
            <div class="image-row">
                    <div class="image-set">
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/rontholi-jewellery/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Rontholi Jewellery Cluster, Nagaon">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/rontholi-jewellery/thumb-1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/rontholi-jewellery/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Rontholi Jewellery Cluster, Nagaon">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/rontholi-jewellery/thumb-2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/rontholi-jewellery/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Rontholi Jewellery Cluster, Nagaon">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/rontholi-jewellery/thumb-3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/rontholi-jewellery/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Rontholi Jewellery Cluster, Nagaon">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/rontholi-jewellery/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/rontholi-jewellery/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Rontholi Jewellery Cluster, Nagaon">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/rontholi-jewellery/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/rontholi-jewellery/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Rontholi Jewellery Cluster, Nagaon">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/rontholi-jewellery/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Rontholi Jewellery Cluster  -->

        </div><!-- @end  -->


        <div id="manipur-content" class="contabblock hidden">
         <span class="cluster">Photographs of Manipur</span>

          <!-- Asharikandi Cluster -->
          <span class="cluster-name">Greater Imphal Jewellery Cluster</span>
          <div class="image-row">
                    <div class="image-set">
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/imphal-jewellery/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Greater Imphal Jewellery Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/imphal-jewellery/thumb-1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/imphal-jewellery/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Greater Imphal Jewellery Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/imphal-jewellery/thumb-2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/imphal-jewellery/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Greater Imphal Jewellery Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/imphal-jewellery/thumb-3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/imphal-jewellery/image-4.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Greater Imphal Jewellery Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/imphal-jewellery/thumb-4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/imphal-jewellery/image-5.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Greater Imphal Jewellery Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/imphal-jewellery/thumb-5.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="example-image-link" href="img/imphal-jewellery/image-6.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="Greater Imphal Jewellery Cluster">
                        <img class="example-image" src="img/imphal-jewellery/thumb-6.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Asharikandi Cluster -->


        </div><!-- @end -->


        <div id="mizoram-content" class="contabblock hidden">
          <h1>Mizoram</h1>

        </div><!-- @end  -->

        <div id="sikkim-content" class="contabblock hidden">
          <h1>Sikkim</h1>

        </div><!-- @end  -->

        <div id="tripura-content" class="contabblock hidden">
          <h1>Tripura</h1>

        </div><!-- @end  -->
        <div id="meghalaya-content" class="contabblock hidden">
          <h1>MIzoram</h1>

        </div><!-- @end  -->

        <div id="arunachal-content" class="contabblock hidden">
          <h1>Arunachal Pradesh</h1>

        </div><!-- @end  -->


    </div><!-- @end #content -->
  </div><!-- @end #w -->

                                     <!--------------------------------------->


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </section>

    <!--==============================footer=================================-->
    <footer>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="wrapper2">
                    <div class="grid_4">
                        <div>&copy; 2014 All right reserved</div>
                        <!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_4">
                        <div>Powered by: Third Eye</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="grid_4">
                        <ul class="list-services" style="float:right;">
                            <li><a class="item-3" href="#"></a></li>
                            <li><a class="item-4" href="#"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#sidemenu a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
      // do nothing because the link is already open
    } else {
      var oldcontent = $('#sidemenu a.open').attr('href');
      var newcontent = $(this).attr('href');

      $(oldcontent).fadeOut('fast', function(){
        $(newcontent).fadeIn().removeClass('hidden');
        $(oldcontent).addClass('hidden');
      });


      $('#sidemenu a').removeClass('open');
      $(this).addClass('open');
    }
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Minify your code to only relevant code and as minimal as possible. If you dynamically switching tabs, than add some parameter to url, to know where you are. Or use local storage (i don't think that it's good idea, thus)

Comment: Hey, add only code related with your question (Example: HTML tabs code) and not all your code with even your `doctype` declaration!

Answer (score 0):

I used this in one of my projects to get the result you are after:

```
$(function() {
    //for bootstrap 3 use 'shown.bs.tab' instead of 'shown' in the next line
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
        //save the latest tab; use cookies if you like 'em better:
        localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    //go to the latest tab, if it exists:
    var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
    if (lastTab) {
        $('a[href="' + lastTab + '"]').click();
    }
});
```

I used bootstrap 3 for the tabs though...